# confirmation not appearing after submit

Tags: jquery, html

I want a confirmation to appear when the user submits a form. The problem is that the confirmation is not appearing and instead it is just navigating the form straight to its destination. Why is the confirmation not appearing? It is not even checking the validation before the confirmation.

Below is html code:

```
<form id='choiceForm' action='assessment.php' method='post'>
    <select name='currentperson' id='currentperson'>
        <option value=''>Select</option>
        <option value='one'>John Trigger</option>
    </select>

    <p id='submitchoicebtn'><button id='choiceSubmit'>Choose Assessment</button></p>
    <div id='currentAlert'></div>
</form>
```

Below is jquery:

```
    function choicevalidation() {
var isDataValid = true;
var currentPerson = document.getElementById("currentperson");
var currentPersonMsg = document.getElementById("currentAlert");
currentPersonMsg.innerHTML = "";

if (currentPerson.value == "") {
    currentPersonMsg.innerHTML = "Please Select a Person";
    isDataValid = false; 
}
else {
    currentPersonMsg.innerHTML = "";
}
    return isDataValid;
}

function showConfirm(){
   console.log(choicevalidation());
   if (choicevalidation()) {
      var confirmMsg = confirm("Are you sure you want to Proceed");
      if (confirmMsg == true) {
        return true;   
      } else {
        return false;
      }
   } else
   {
      return false;
   }
} 

$('#choiceForm').on('submit', showConfirm);
```

**UPDATE:**

Below is my actual code but problem I am receiving is this error:

Jquery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


       function choicevalidation() {

                var isDataValid = true;

                var currentAssesO = document.getElementById("currentAssessment");

                var currentAssesMsgO = document.getElementById("currentAlert");

          currentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "";


      if (currentAssesO.value == ""){
          $('#targetdiv').hide();
          currentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select an Assessment to edit from the Assessment Drop Down Menu";
          isDataValid = false; 
        }else{
            currentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "";
        }
            return isDataValid;


        }


             function showConfirm(){

              var examInput = document.getElementById('curentAssessment').value;
              var dateInput = document.getElementById('currentDate').value;
              var timeInput = document.getElementById('currentTime').value;

              if (choicevalidation()) {

             var confirmMsg=confirm("Are you sure you want to take the following Assessment:" + "\n" + "Exam: " + examInput +  "\n" + "Date: " + dateInput + "\n" + "Time: " + timeInput);

             if (confirmMsg==true)
             {
             return true;    
         }else {
        return false;
      }
  } else{
      return false;
   }
} 

   $('#choiceForm').on('submit', showConfirm);    


    </script>
```

PHP/HTML code:

```
<?php

// connect to the database


//query which compiles modules drop down menu


$moduleHTML = "";
$moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">' . PHP_EOL;
$moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>' . PHP_EOL;

while ($sqlstmt->fetch()) {
    $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s_%3$s">%1$s - %2$s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName, $dbModuleId);
}

$moduleHTML .= '</select>';

$pHTML = "";


?> 

<h1>TAKE AN ASSESSMENT</h1>   

<form action="<?php
echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validation(event);"> 
<table> 
<tr> 
<th>Module: <?php
echo $moduleHTML;
?></th> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<p><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" /></p> 
<div id="moduleAlert"></div> 
<div id="targetdiv"></div> 
</form> 

<?php

if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])) {
    //query which compiles drop down menu below


    $sessionHTML = '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">' . PHP_EOL;
    $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>' . PHP_EOL;

    while ($sessionqrystmt->fetch()) {
        $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i", strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;
    }


    $sessionHTML .= '</select>';


    $assessmentform = "<div id='lt-container'> 
<form action='" . htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "' method='post' id='assessmentForm'> 
<p id='warnings'>{$pHTML}</p> 
{$outputmodule} 
<p><strong>Assessments:</strong> {$sessionHTML} </p>   
</form> 
</div>";

    echo $assessmentform;

    $choosesession = " 
<div id='rt-container'> 
<form id='choiceForm' action='assessment.php' method='post'> 

    <p><strong>Chosen Assessment:</strong></p> 
    <table> 
    <tr> 
    <th></th> 
    <td><input type='hidden' id='currentId' name='Idcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td> 
    </tr> 
    </table> 
    <p id='submitchoicebtn'><button id='choiceSubmit'>Choose Assessment</button></p> 
    <div id='currentAlert'></div> 
    </form> 

    </div> 
";

    echo $choosesession;

}



?>
```

Comment: You missed " in var confirmMsg=confirm("... line.

Comment: You have a missing `"` quote in the `confirm` - is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error, so the JS is failing and the browser is submiting the form.

This line is missing the end '"'.

```
 var confirmMsg=confirm("Are you sure you want to Proceed);
```

Change it to:

```
 var confirmMsg=confirm("Are you sure you want to Proceed");
```

**Edit**

Change the event you're triggering the confirmation on. You're triggering it on an "onClick", which is probably happening after the form is already submited, change your last line to:

```
   $('#choiceForm').on('submit', showConfirm);
```

That will trigger the box *before* the submit is executed. Let me know if that fixes it for you.

Comment: Hi, I add the quote in but still no luck

Comment: @user1830984 Added an edit to my original answer, let me know if now it works.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was gonna work but it didn't. I updated code in question so you can see what it looks like

Comment: @user1830984 It works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/baxGm/ what error are you seeing?

Comment: There is no error, it just still navigates to the assessment.php after submit, no confirmation or validation appearing

Comment: @user1830984 Did you check the JSFiddle I posted on my previous comment? Does it work for you? If not, what browser / version are you using?

Comment: I think there is an error once I managed to download firefox and looked at is error console, it is an character encoding problem. I will post my main script. The above code I posted was a created example but looks like I will have to post my main script

Comment: There is no error, I realise the error was there because obviously I have not set up the other page the form navigates to. Anyway I have posted my script in an update. there is no updates and I will remove my update once the problem is solved but please have a look at my script and just see where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Deleteman answer works, but you need to prevent from submitting, when nothing has been selected or when you click cancel in the confirmation popup . So i will just add to the condition:

```
return false;
```

so the entire js would be:

```
function choicevalidation() {
var isDataValid = true;
var currentPerson = document.getElementById("currentperson");
var currentPersonMsg = document.getElementById("currentAlert");
currentPersonMsg.innerHTML = "";

if (currentPerson.value == "") {
    currentPersonMsg.innerHTML = "Please Select a Person";
    isDataValid = false; 
}
else {
    currentPersonMsg.innerHTML = "";
}
    return isDataValid;
}

function showConfirm(){
   console.log(choicevalidation());
   if (choicevalidation()) {
      var confirmMsg = confirm("Are you sure you want to Proceed");
      if (confirmMsg == true) {
        return true;   
      } else {
        return false;
      }
   } else
   {
      return false;
   }
} 

$('#choiceForm').on('submit', showConfirm);
```